# Python dynamic dictionary + print html output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am performing computation on complex query and getting below  dictionary as final output and now want to print that dict in html format  without hardcoding column names as it is dynamic.

If column is not there then add 0 in the report.

```
data = {'Author1': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                        {'Microsoft': 248,
                         'Ubuntu': 24,
                         'IOS': 24,
                         'Solaris': 24,
                         'C': 248}),
 'Author2': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                           {'Microsoft': 38,
                            'Ubuntu': 38,
                            'IOS': 38,
                            'Go': 38,
                            'C': 38}),
 'Author3': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                    {'Microsoft': 2,
                     'IOS': 2,
                     'Go': 2,
                     'C': 2})}
```

Output

```
 Name       Microsoft  Ubuntu IOS Go Solaris C
Author1       248        24   24  0   24     248  
Author2        38        38    38 38   0      38
Author3        2         0     2  2    0      2
```

code:

```
html = '<table><tr><th>' + '</th><th>'.join(data.keys()) + '</th></tr>'

for row in zip(*data.values()):
    html += '<tr><td>' + '</td><td>'.join(row) + '</td></tr>'

html += '</table>'

print(html)
```

This code errors out bec of default dict inside a dictionary, which needs to be removed.

Comment: If you get an error, you must show the full error message. Anyway, remember that a dict does not preserve order and I do not think that what you need are `defaultdic(dict, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

how about using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) it does all the [job](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html) for you

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
{body}
    </body>
</html>
"""
with open("test.html","w") as file:
    file.write( html.format(body=df.to_html(na_rep="0")) )
```

this result in this table

[image]

use `.T` to transpose the table

```
with open("test2.html","w") as file:
    file.write( html.format(body=df.T.to_html(na_rep="0")) )
```

and result in

[image]

---

without pandas, them I would go like this

```
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
{body}
    </body>
</html>
"""

table="""
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
{thead}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
{tbody}
  </tbody>
</table>
"""

thead="""
<tr style="text-align: right;">
{th}
</tr>
"""
th="""<th>{}</th>\n"""
td="""<td>{}</td>\n"""
tr="""<tr>{}</tr>\n"""

def manual_table(data, colums):
    head = thead.format(th= "".join( map(th.format,["Name"]+colums)))
    pieces=[]
    for autor, value in data.items():
        temp = [autor]
        temp.extend( value.get(c,0) for c in colums )
        pieces.append(tr.format( "".join(td.format(x) for x in temp )) )
    body = "\n".join(pieces)
    return table.format(thead=head, tbody=body)

colums="Microsoft  Ubuntu IOS Go Solaris C".split()

with open("test3.html","w") as file:
    file.write( html.format(body=manual_table(data, colums)))
```

first I build some templates, so I get something that I can read at the end, then I go inside out filling those templates accordingly and in the order that I impose by the `colums` variable.

this result in

[image]

---

One of the problem with your code is that you don't fetch the values in the correct order, one partial solution for that is

```
colums="Microsoft  Ubuntu IOS Go Solaris C".split()
for row in data.values():
    table += '<tr><td>' + '</td><td>'.join(str(row.get(c,0)) for c in colums) + '</td></tr>'
```

if you don't want to hard code the column's names, but get them from the data, then you can do this

```
>>> {k for v in data.values() for k in v }
{'C', 'IOS', 'Solaris', 'Ubuntu', 'Microsoft', 'Go'}
>>>
```

---

about your question in the comments, yes you can and is very easy with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum), like for example

```
>>> df
           Author1  Author2  Author3
C            248.0     38.0      2.0
Go             NaN     38.0      2.0
IOS           24.0     38.0      2.0
Microsoft    248.0     38.0      2.0
Solaris       24.0      NaN      NaN
Ubuntu        24.0     38.0      NaN
>>> df["Total"] = df.T.sum()
>>> df
           Author1  Author2  Author3  Total
C            248.0     38.0      2.0  288.0
Go             NaN     38.0      2.0   40.0
IOS           24.0     38.0      2.0   64.0
Microsoft    248.0     38.0      2.0  288.0
Solaris       24.0      NaN      NaN   24.0
Ubuntu        24.0     38.0      NaN   62.0
```

just play around with it until you get the desire result, and check the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) so you know all the toys it have

Comment: Wow, `na_rep='0'` automatically convert the empty dicts to 0! Clean output despite the poor input... Nice

Comment: Using pandas looks great! Is it possible to add "Total" column in the table using pandas, Or do I need to compute myself before passing the values?

Comment: @Copperfield: I would like to add in pandas style colour to alternate row in table. Can you please let me know.

Comment: @VinodHC I'm not that familiar with pandas, maybe you can do something with the `formatters` parameter of `to_html`, but I don't know how, make a new question about it so a more knowledgeable user can help you with it